# Eclipse ADT (Theme and Icon) is broken after updating Android SDK

Tags: eclipse, adt

after adding new Components (Android SDK Tools and Developer Tools) to Eclipse, the beautiful splashscreen (on startup) and App Icon (in the doc) are gone when I run Eclipse. Right before I start it, the ADT Icon is shown - but after its starting it is changing to the Eclipse Icon. I am running Mac OSX Mountain Lion. (ADT Icon: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-kcAmqYmpgVM/UKPPGbaJNnI/AAAAAAAAkp0/dp-vtDYvnA0/w248-h248-p/sdk-adt-ide.png)

What can I do to prevent this? Without the different Icons: Its hard to distinguish the different Eclipse Apps running.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

## ITS FIXED

Read more here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the previous posts before (thanks at this point) I will now post the official responses here (from the forum link I posted up there).

currently there is no propper solution but a workaround (last paragraph)

> **Project Member** [link to post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41126#c29)
>   Apologies to all of you for the delay in fixing this. I am waiting on
>   Eclipse to release 4.2 SR2 before updating ADT's Eclipse version to be
>   4.2.2. According to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Juno/Simultaneous_Release_Plan#SR2, 4.2.2
>   should have been released on 2/22, so I expect it will be out anytime
>   soon.
>
> We have already updated the ADT bundle to include egit by default, so
>   if you are just looking for egit, you shouldn't have to install
>   anything by yourself.
>
> Everyone else, should do the following:
>   - go to Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites, and uncheck/remove the Juno update site.
>   - Whenever you install any software, make sure that Eclipse platform 4.2 is not brought in.

In addition to that there is a second post that there is a solution (fix) upcoming with the upcoming release of Eclipse:

> **Project Member** (11.03.2013) [link to post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41126#c42) 
>  
>   With https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/53181/1, we are now
>   building with e4 internally. We'll try to make a preview available
>   within a week.
>
> See Comment#29 for workarounds. Most of you should be able to get
>   things working as long as you remove the Juno repository from your
>   list of P2 repositories.

### Update:

> **Date: 10.05.2013**
>   IF YOU HAVE THIS ISSUE TRYING TO INSTALL eGIT
>  -> **eGIT is NOW included in the Bundle** on the android developers download site.
>   Code with fixes still in review - nothing changed on the main problem.

Hope to be helpful at this point. Will edit when things are happening.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with the same thing, but I managed to fix both the app Icon and splash screen on mac.

1. To replace the Icon:

   Go to the package content of the Eclipe ADT. Go to the Resources
   folder and delete Eclipse.icns. Just to be safe, open the Info.plist
   and replace Bundle Icon:

   ```
   <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
           <string>adt.icns</string>
   ```
2. Now to replace the Splash Screen:

One quick way is to search inside the /plugins folder for "splash". You'll see the ADP splash and the Eclipse one. Since they are on different folders, just copy the adt splash screen image and replace over the eclipse one.

Finished, now you got your old ADT appearance back.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating to ADT 21.1 in Windows x86, looking around my eclipse config file I found the following directive:

```
-showsplash
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
```

I navigated there and found the default eclipse splash bmp, I simply replaced it with the ADT splash BMP which I found here:

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\plugins\com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
```

Upon restarting my browser I had my ADT Splash screen back.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to do it on my Mac.. failed because I can't find your config entry ony my mac.

Comment: You should find the eclipse directory first.His method works for me in my mac. But what should we do for icon?

Answer (score 0):

On mac, you will find this setting inside of the eclipse package in your ADT folder. Simply right click on the Eclipse application and select "Show Package Contents".

Inside of the contents folder, there is a file named "Info.plist" that contains all of the settings for the app icon and the splash screen. I found that mine had duplicate icon definitions so I just deleted the non-ADT ones and pointed the splash to the right location.

For the splash screen, you will need to use the full path to the bmp file. This should be something like:

```
/{adt-install-location}/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_{your-build-number}/splash.bmp
```

You will need to check in your plugins directory to see what your build number is since it may be different for you than it is for me. After changing these lines in the plist file, save it and you should be back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

Just:

1. Open package for your Eclipse.app
2. Goto Contents/Resources, and delete the Eclipse.icns

Then your beautiful ADT icon will be shown again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the route where you can find the `adt.ico` file to whatever use you want/need:

```
<ADT-installation-folder>\eclipse\plugins\com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_<Build-number>\icons
```

Just for reference: my ADT-installation-folder: `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-developer-tools` & my Build-number: `22.3.0.v201310242005-887826`

Info source: [Add .ico file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/1e21cccca793acfcfe8e34f5eace21c3ff5f2271%5E!/#F0) (Thanks to Siva Velusamy that made this patch back on Oct 24 2012)